# Media streams capturing issue in MV3 (chrome extension) with respect to constraints

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, screen-capture, get-display-media

Description
When using the getUserMedia API in Chrome to capture audio from specific Chrome tabs using the chromeMediaSource and chromeMediaSourceId constraints, the API is not behaving consistently. The issue manifests as the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Invalid state error."

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Get the streamId from the desktopCapture API

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
      ["tab", "audio"],
      tab,
      (streamId, options) => {});
```

Here, tab` argument consists of the tab info

Use the getUserMedia API to get the streams

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
    },
  },
  video: {
    optional: [],
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
    },
  },
}).then((streams)=>{});
```

Here, the "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Invalid state error." will occur

Expected behavior
The getUserMedia API should consistently capture audio from Chrome tabs using the specified chromeMediaSource and chromeMediaSourceId constraints without resulting in an "Invalid state error."

OS : iOS
Browser : chrome
Version : 119.0.6045.199
Additional context
I am working on the chrome extension (Manifest Version-3) so using the getUserMedia API to get the streams from the particular streamId and as mentioned above facing the Issues while capturing the media.

For reference use the below doc for more info on the errors for the different constraints of the getUserMedia API tried
[getUserMedia-DOC](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CQXxIqrd5WS0sDzHr5douaino35Iwm8aq7cQLn7-HFc/edit)

My use case is that I want to capture the audios only from the tabs but need the feature like tab switching.
So I want to first bring up the below so that the user can select the tab to be captured :
[Refer image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYpZt.png)

After selecting the tab the user must get the UI of the capturing like below :
[Refer image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz7Cn.png)

To acheive the above I tried using the follwoing chrome APIs :

1. getUserMedia - The issue with this I am not able to capture the particular streamID
2. getDisplayMedia - The issue with this is I am not able to remove the window sharing option as I only want the tab capturing options